# Orthogonal transformations and reflections

Tags: linear-algebra, geometric-algebras

In the context of geometric algebra, why is it that any orthogonal transformation can be expressed as successive reflections? (Both, a mathematical and an intuitive explanation would be great)

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: This is the [Cartan-Dieudonne theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%E2%80%93Dieudonn%C3%A9_theorem), which you can easily find a proof of (probably on math.stackexchange). Are you asking specifically why this means we can factor a versor into a product of vectors in geometric algebra? Otherwise this doesn't really have anything to do with geometric algebra.